# Disks not showing on fresh install

Tags: partitioning, disk, fdisk, disk-management, disk-image

Firstly, I have 10+years on Windows sys admin, but i'm new to the linux world

I've just deployed a dedicated server with 4x9TB disks for my backups using hetzner server

I used their recovery console, installed a from an image.
However i'm not seeing each disk
Here is the disk layout:
[Disk layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x20b9.png)

But when I browse the filesystem i cannot see these disks in the
[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ApJd.png)

Any pointers what to do next?

Selecting one disk, it appears [Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQFqM.png)

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: the image name i build from on hetzner is called ubuntu 1604-xenial-64-minimal

Comment: The XFCE desktop is EOL on 16.04, only Ubuntu Server (no desktop), Unity 7 (default `ubuntu-desktop`) and Kylin desktop is still supported on xenial/16.04. You might want to consider changing desktops (root is not a good idea on desktop, and is disabled if using wayland and it's higher security model) or moving to a release which still has XFCE suipported.

Comment: There are /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd, the 4 9TB HDDs, under Devices. I can see them.

Comment: thanks @mikewhatever, i can see them in the partition manager software, but not as drives/folders, i need them to appear drives/folders so I can start filling them up, how do i do that?

Comment: Does /dev/sda etc. exist as a file or not? Your confusion may be that you think it should be a folder under /dev that you can access as a drive, but it is not. You need to mount your drives to a folder first.

Comment: Taking another look at your screenshots, it seems that at least /dev/sda is set up as a RAID, which makes it more complex than just mounting it somewhere. I'm not familiar with RAID setups, but at some point in your installation you should have been asked how to set it up.